# Cant backup sql database with c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database-backups, mdf

I tried this code samples

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\schoolmate.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
string sql = "BACKUP Database '" +Application.StartupPath+@"\schoolmate.mdf'" +" TO DISK ='D:\\schoolmate-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".bak'";
con2.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con2);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it gives a Incorrect syntax  error.

And also tried

```
string sql = "BACKUP Database 'schoolmate.mdf' TO DISK ='D:\\schoolmate-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".bak'";
```

and

```
string sql = "BACKUP Database 'schoolmate' TO DISK ='D:\\schoolmate-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".bak'";
```

Which gives database not found error on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Add a breakpoint on `con2.Open();` and check the value of `sql`. Try to run it on SSMS. You will probably find what is wrong.

Comment: Refer to this. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/creating-sql-server-backup-file-with-C-Sharp/

Comment: What is your `sql` looks like in debugger before you execute it?

Comment: "BACKUP Database 'D:\\works\\windows\\Schoolmate V2.0\\bin\\Debug\\schoolmate.mdf' TO DISK ='D:\\schoolmate-635616793105894858.bak'"  this is the sql with file path

Comment: Is `schoolmate.mdf` in that folder?

Comment: Yes file is there. And error is Incorrect syntax near 'D:\works\windows\Schoolmate V2.0\bin\Debug\schoolmate.mdf'.

Comment: Backup takes the db name as a param

Comment: Is that suppose to be schoolmate or schoolmate.mdf, which is the mdf file's name. Is database name different from it?

Comment: I guess the database name would be schoolmate, though it may differ from the file name. You should check and see how the db is called in SQL Server. You also not need the folder, so it should be something like `BACKUP Database schoolmate ...`. Note that you do not need the quotes around the db name. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string sql = "BACKUP Database [schoolmate] TO DISK ='D:\\schoolmate-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".bak'";
```